# How to express this data type in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, types, ruby-3

I have this preudo code that describes a type

```
    type MyType1 = {
        type: :type1,
        field1: number,
        field2: any
    } | {
        type: :type2,
        field3: string
    } | {
        type: :type4,
        field4: SomeOtherType
    } | {
        type: :type5,
        field5: string,
        field6: integer,
        field7: float
    } | {
        type: :type6
    }
```

I've expressed it this way in Ruby:

```
    class MyType1
        attr_reader :type, :field1, :field2, :field3, :field4, :field5, :field6, :field7

        def init_with_type_1(field1:, field2:)
          @type = :type1
          @field1 = field1
          @field2 = field2
        end

        def init_with_type_2(field3:)
          @type = :type2
          @field3 = field3
        end

        # and so on...

    end
```

Is there a better, more idiomatic, more simple way?

I don't consider using third-party gems and libraries.

Comment: A better and simpler way would be to use only functions and maps. But it's not necessarily more idiomatic because it can be clunky writing functional code in Ruby.

Comment: In Ruby, I would probably define a super-class `Type` with sub-classes `Type1`, `Type2` etc.

Comment: Strategy pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
Type1 = Struct.new(:field1, :field2)
Type2 = Struct.new(:field3)

class MyType1
  def initialize(some_type_item)
    @data = some_type_item
  end
  def self.init_with_type_1(f1, f2)
    self.new(Type1.new(f1,f2))
  end
  def type
    @data.class # Or @data.class.name, if you prefer
  end
  def field1
    # Raises exception, if we don't have Type1 
    @data.field1
  end
end
```

I coded this explicitly, but some of the work (for instance the definition of field1 etc.) could be made simpler (less typing) using the `Forwardable` module from the Ruby Standard Library. Also, the `init_with_type` methods could be generated using a loop, which could simplify things if you have really many different types you want to store here.

I modeled this close to your initial solution, though I ask myself, why you introduce a class `MyType1` for this; after having defined Type1, Type2 etc., I would simply do a

```
myTypeVar = Type2.new(4711)
puts "myTypeVar is a #{myTypeVar.class}"
puts myTypeVar.field3 # OK
puts myTypeVar.field1 # Exception!
```

Comment: even if that represents `MyType1`, it doesn't simplify the things, but overcomplicates them.

Comment: @Khinkala2 : Actually, that's why I wrote below how I would go at this problem. IMO, inventing MyType1 is unnecessary here. If all the types share certain features, perhaps you would better use a `Module` as a mixin. Unless we see how you plan to use the type, it is hard to recommend. BTW: My approach looks complicated if you manually type out all the methods. I did this only for clarity, but if you have many nested types, you would generate them using a loop, and this would then less code in the end. For instance, you could auto-generate the _field**n**_ and _init_with_type_**n**_ methods.